# How can I dockerize multi module Spring app?

Tags: java, spring, maven, multi-module, hexagonal-architecture

I'm trying to dockerize my multi module application (i'm using hexagonal architecture with Port and Adapters pattern).
Here is the structure of my application:
[App structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pt6Gm.png)

My root pom looks in this way:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

4.0.0

```
<groupId>org.example</groupId>
<artifactId>Example project</artifactId>
<packaging>pom</packaging>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>17</source>
                <target>17</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
<modules>
    <module>domain</module>
    <module>infrastructure</module>
    <module>application</module>
    <module>fwm-launcher</module>
</modules>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.6.5</version>
</parent>

<properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>18</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>18</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>
```

Answer (score 0):

Below blog talks all about it. jib-maven-plugin is the easiest option to dockerize your app

https://www.baeldung.com/jib-dockerizing